Inverse Relation for Allocating an Amount
This question came up in the context of project finance. It is my original question.
Quick Version

A project has upfront cost $X$, and ongoing cost $Z$. (Z is less than X).
There are the same $N$ contributors to upfront and ongoing costs
The direct allocation method is that if Person A gives 1/20 of the upfront cost, then Person A is responsible for 1/20 of the on-going cost.
What is the inverse allocation?

Inverse: If Person A gives $x_u\%$ of $X$, and there are 3 Persons contributing to the upfront cost, then Person A is inversely responsible for $x_o\%$ of ongoing costs. Where x_o would typically be greater than x_u.



The idea is that the Person who contributes least to the much higher upfront cost, is responsible for a greater proportion of the much lower ongoing cost. The question is how do I define this proportion based on Person A's initial ratio, and the number of contributors to the upfront cost involved? (Always at least 2).
Example (Always at least 2 Persons)

Person A gives 100% upfront, thus is responsible for 0% of the ongoing.

Persons B, C, etc. divide the ongoing evenly.


Person A gives 0% upfront, thus is responsible for 100% of the ongoing.

Persons B, C, etc had paid all of the upfront, so are tied to none of the ongoing.



I'm looking for a formula. So if I plugged in percentages (A, B, C) = (20, 40, 40), I'd get out something like (A',B'C') = (60, 20, 20) or whatever the fair inverse is.
What are your ideas?
Is there a more appropriate name for this type of problem?

Here are things I attempted
Upfront
A 20 or 1/5 or 20%
B 40
C 40
Now find the Ongoing percentages they should pay, based on the premise that those who contribute less upfront, have greater responsibility ongoing.
Try 1: Take reciprocal and add: 5/1 + 5/2 + 5/2 = 20/2 = 10... but if we weight this by the initial ratios, we're back to where we were. What should the weighting be?
Try 2: Take complement and add 4/5 + 3/5 + 3/5 = 10/5 = 2.

A: 20% of 2 = 0.4 or 40%
B: 40% of 2 = 0.8 or 80%
C: 40% of 2 = 0.8 or 80%
We are of course over 100%. Doesn't work.

Try 3: Take relative contribution and then ??

A: 20:80  = 1/4 or 3/12
B: 40:60 = 2/3 or 8/12
C: 40:60 = 2/3 or 8/12
Total 19/12... Looks ugly. Should I stop?
19/12 = 57/36. 1/3 of 19/12 if 19/36. Is this important since there are 3 people?

Try 4: Find the even split, and allocate the gap to those over/under

If there are N Persons, the even split is 100%/N
3 Persons: Even split = 33%.

A: 20, so 33-20 is additional 12. 33+12= 45
B: 40, so 33-40 is fewer 7. 33-7 = 26
C: 40, s0 33-40 is fewer 7. 33-7 = 26
45+26+26 = 97  $\ne$ 100
Use Multiplication for "Additional 12%, Fewer 7%" instead.
(40 * .93)*2 + (20 * 1.12) = 96.8  $\ne$ 100
(33 * .93)*2 + (33 * 1.12) = 98.34 $\ne$ 100




It is not clear precisely what you want from "inverse allocation".   If the upfront payments from A, B, C were $0%, 75%, 25%$ then is it not obvious this should lead to ongoing $100%, 0%, 0%$.

Zero is an edge case. What's most import is how this flips when everyone involved contributed more than zero. This is a very strange problem. Just something I imagined and tried to formalize, to see if there was a fair way to invert the responsibility.

If you want equal equivalent allocation, you want to find a Net Present Value of the ongoing costs to compare with the upfront costs, giving an implicit combined cost in today's money.  Everybody might be expected to contribute $\frac1N$ of this cost combining upfront costs and NPV of ongoing costs, so their upfront contributions can be deducted from this combined cost leaving how much of the NPV they are expected to contribute, and then you could make their ongoing contributions proportionate to their share of the NPV.

I've found a few potential loopholes after posting this and some rumination. I think I can add my next attempts to answer this (or a modification to it) in a few days.
